# Instant or cook and serve pudding?

Tags: substitutions

Making a diabetic healthy strawberry pie which calls for sugar free jello and sugar free cook and serve vanilla pudding.  I can only find sugar free INSTANT vanilla pudding.  Can I substitute the instant pudding mix for the cook and serve pudding mix?

Comment: It is impossible to make a diabetic healthy product from strawberries, considering their glycemic index.

Comment: @MentallyHealthyPerson Based on the ingredients listed, I doubt that this pie has any strawberries in it.  Rather, it seems that it contains strawberry flavored sugar free Jell-O.

Comment: @GeriJackson It would be helpful to have a more complete recipe, but my guess is that you are prepping the pudding and Jell-O, and putting them into a pie crust of some sort, then putting the whole thing in the fridge without cooking.  Assuming that this is the case, I have difficulty imagining how the difference between "cook and eat" pudding and "instant pudding" would matter.

Comment: It's impossible to give you advice without the recipe. Sometimes the heat is important, sometimes cold is better.